# Repeating code, looping columns until blank cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a table of 130 columns and 65 rows of which I select a column, filter, print and then hide that column before moving on to the next iteration.

The code must stop when it has completed the last column.

My thinking is that I should have planned this in a more logical fashion and had some sort of code referencing the filter and print requirements.

Nevertheless here is a portion / extract.

```
' Select 5th customer, 9th column (field), filter to exclude blanks,
'select a print range with column offset from A1 and dynamic row range

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
    "<>" ' selects "blank"
Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(0, 8)).Select ' selects A1 to 9th column.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'selects dynamic rectangle A1 to G1 down, defined print selection

Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1 'print above defined print selection


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9 ' filters on "select all"
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Material / SITE]]").Select


 ' Select 6th customer, 10th column (field), filter to exclude blanks,
'select a print range with column offset from A1 and dynamic row range

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "<>" ' selects "blank"
Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(0, 9)).Select ' selects A1 to 10th column.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'selects dynamic rectangle A1 to G1 down, defined print selection

Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1 'print above defined print selection


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10 ' filters on "select all"
Columns("j:j").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Material / SITE]]").Select


' Select 7th customer, 11th column (field), filter to exclude blanks,
'select a print range with column offset from A1 and dynamic row range

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
    "<>" ' selects "blank"
Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(0, 10)).Select ' selects A1 to 11th column.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'selects dynamic rectangle A1 to G1 down, defined print selection

Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1 'print above defined print selection


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11 ' filters on "select all"
Columns("k:k").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Material / SITE]]").Select


' Select 8th customer, 12th column (field), filter to exclude blanks,
'select a print range with column offset from A1 and dynamic row range

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
    "<>" ' selects "blank"
Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(0, 11)).Select ' selects A1 to 12th column.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'selects dynamic rectangle A1 to G1 down, defined print selection

Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1 'print above defined print selection


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12 ' filters on "select all"
Columns("l:l").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Material / SITE]]").Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a counter to loop through the columns, then you only need one piece of code:

NB: you will need the counter to run from whatever your first column is to 130 + that column (not 1 to 130)

psuedocode:

```
For counter = 1 to 130 (number of customers)
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=counter,    Criteria1:= _
"<>" ' selects "blank"
 Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(0, counter-1)).Select ' selects A1 to    11th column.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'selects dynamic rectangle A1 to G1 down, defined print selection

Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1 'print above defined print selection


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=counter ' filters on "select all"
Columns("counter:counter").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Material / SITE]]").Select

Next counter
```

Comment: It would go a lot faster if all the `.Select`s were avoided.

Comment: Thanks Jpad and Scott, i have learnt a lot whilst implementing the code. I now have a Run time err 13 , type mismatch at Columns("counter:counter").Select

Comment: Take the speech marks off: columns(counter & ":" & counter)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jpad but I just don't understand! Are you saying that I should use      columns(counter & ":" & counter)   as is?

Comment: I have tried editing and pasting the suggested solution in various forms but unfortunately nothing seems to work. Please assist once again.

Comment: instead of 

Columns("counter:counter").Select

try

Columns(counter).select

Although I Agree with @Scott Craner that the selects are going to make it slow. Maybe get it working, then see about changing that part

Comment: Will do Jpad. I will report back.Thanks again.

Comment: @jpad Brilliant , that works. Thanks immensely for your assistance and patience.

Comment: @Scott Craner  I will have a look at the .select that you suggested once this exercise is done and dusted. Baby steps for me.